# Como listar categorias e subcategorias no select?

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomia

Pessoal eu tenho 2 taxonomias personalizadas em um post, são elas, Cidade e Estados. **Porém eu quero usar apenas a taxonomia Cidades** e cada cidade colocar ela **sendo Ascendente do seu respectivo Estado**. Feito isso gostaria de fazer com quer esses 2 selects funcionassem da seguinte forma: O **primeiro Select me daria as opções de Estado e o Segundo Select as opções de Cidade de acordo com o Estado selecionado**! Eu tenho esses código abaixo, mas não sei bem como fazer isso que preciso. Aqui também tem uma imagem de como hoje em dia está esse select: https://prnt.sc/vz0r92

```
        <form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="filter">

        <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-3 estados">
                <?php
                $taxonomy = 'estados'; ?>
                <?php $terms = get_terms($taxonomy); ?>

                <select id="<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>" name="<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>" class="span2">
                    <?php if ($terms = get_terms(array('taxonomy' => 'estados'))) : ?>

                        <option data-title="0" value="0">Selecione um Estado</option>

                        <?php foreach ($terms as $term) : ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $term->term_id; ?>"><?php echo ucfirst($term->name); ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 cidades">
                <?php
                $taxonomy = 'cidades'; ?>
                <?php $terms = get_terms($taxonomy); ?>

                <select id="<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>" name="<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>" class="span4">
                    <?php if ($terms = get_terms(array('taxonomy' => 'cidades'))) : ?>

                        <option data-title="0" value="0">Selecione uma Cidade</option>
                        
                        <?php foreach ($terms as $term) : ?>
                            <option data-title="<?php echo $term->term_name; ?>" value="<?php echo $term->term_id; ?>"><?php echo ucfirst($term->name); ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                </select>

            </div>


            <div class="col-md-3">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-busca">Buscar</button>
            </div>

        </div>


    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para verificar se o termo é pai voce pode checar o atributo parent. Se for 0 quer dizer que ele é um estado, se não, cidade.

```
$locais = get_terms($taxonomy);

foreach($terms as $term) {
    if ($term->parent == 0) { 
      //estados
    }else {
     //cidades
    }
}
```

Comment: Certo, Mas como eu consigo relacionar o estado com a cidade?

Comment: Na hora de criar sua taxonomia, você deve declarar que ela tem hierarquia:

 `register_taxonomy(
  'local', //taxonomy name
  'user', //object for which the taxonomy is created
  array( //taxonomy details
   'public' => true,
   'rewrite' =>  array('slug' => 'instaladores', 'with_front' => false, 'hierarchical' => true),
   'hierarchical' => true,
...`


declarando isso, vai aparecer o select para voce relacionar na tela de criar uma cidade

não esqueça de preencher o parent_item e parent_label dentro do array de labels na hora de registrar a taxonomia